# How to initially show SearchBar in the NavigationBar but still have it hide as the user scrolls up?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm building out a basic ViewController containing a CollectionViewController with multiple sections. I would like to have a UISearchBar contained in the NavigationBar, but it appears Swift only allows two behavior options: initially hide the search bar and then show it once the user scrolls down, or always show the search bar.

I'd like for the search bar to function like it does in, say, the Messages app, where it appears without the user having to scroll, and then hides as the user scrolls down the page. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I'm fairly new to iOS development and haven't been able to find any previously asked questions for this.

Example of how it looks where the search bar is always present:

[image]

Example of how it looks where the user has to scroll down to have the search bar appear:

[image]

The initialization of the controller and search bar:

```swift
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let search = UISearchBar()
    search.placeholder = "Search"
    search.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    search.sizeToFit()
    search.barStyle = .default
    return search
}()

// Truncated...

// Called from viewDidLoad()
func configureSearchBar() {
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchController.isActive = true
    definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationItem.title = "Test Title"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

I know this code won't produce the expected behavior, but is there a simple modification I could make to have it behave properly?

Comment: "_the Messages app, where it appears without the user having to scroll,_ ", well when you just launch the messages app, it does not show the search field by default and only shows when you scroll up while you're at the top

Comment: Well , why don't you set the first cell of your _Custom CollectionView_ as a search bar , that way whenever the collectionView loads, the search bar will always be present at the top and when you scroll, it will be hidden and then when you again scroll to the top, it will be visible . But that would not appear to be part of the navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the power of UISearchController without using your scrollView.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to initially show the UISearchbar. At this point I am not really sure if that's intended by Apple or if it's just another hack to get a simple behaviour to work.

In `viewDidLoad` after setting up your `UISearchController` call:

```
present(searchController, animated: true)
```

This will then animate and extend the navigationBar and show the search bar. Don't forget to dismiss it again when you're done editing the text inside the bar. This needs to be done even if you're initially hiding the search bar because if you don't it will be retained and you end up with a leak.

**Edit:**
To answer the rest of your question I provided some demo code to get the idea across:

You can observe the contentOffset and dismiss it when it has a certain value:

```
observable = self.viewDictionary.tableView.observe(\.contentOffset) { [unowned self] value in
        guard let offset = value else { return }
        if offset.y > 30 {
            self.navigationItem.searchController?.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

The observer code uses a simple extension found & explained [here](https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/04/24/bindings-with-kvo-and-keypaths/) but using the standard library version works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true` in viewDidLoad()

Set the scroll view contentOffset to the inverse of the searchBar height in viewWillAppear().

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let offset = -(searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset), animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in ViewDidLoad

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
}
```